# How to pull data out from datatable

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable

I have create a click function to show modal....

Inside modal I create a datatable to show item_id and quantity.

If I want to pull the other data to put inside modal... HOw to make it...

In console.log show i still have **item_name** etc can pull BUT now Im only know how to set inside datatables.

This code can use for click tbody then show modal. simple and nice to use.

```
  $('#stock-enquiry-table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
          var data = table.row(this).data();
          **console.log(data);**

          $('#selected-item-id').val(data.item_id);
          table_item.ajax.reload();

          $('#modal-content').modal({
            show: true
          });
      });
```

Please teach show the data inside modal but not in datatable.
Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be half way done, actually more than half way

you have all the data in variable `data`

You just need to write the javascript to set the data into the modal.

I'd suggest writing a generic function for it.

```
function setDataInModal(data) {
   $('#input1').val(data.key1);
   $('#input2').val(data.key2);
   $('#input3').val(data.key3);
   ...
}
```

call the function before `$('#modal-content').modal({show: true});`

---

## Update after conversation in comments

```js
var data = [{
    item_id: "2",
    item_code: "PA",
    name: "Product A",
    short_description: null,
    description: null
  },
  {
    item_id: "3",
    item_code: "PAA",
    name: "Product AA",
    short_description: null,
    description: null
  },
  {
    item_id: "4",
    item_code: "PAAA",
    name: "Product AAA",
    short_description: null,
    description: null
  }
]

$('#table').DataTable({
  data: data,
  columns: [{
      data: 'item_id',
      title: 'id'
    },
    {
      data: 'item_code',
      title: 'code'
    },
    {
      data: 'name',
      title: 'name'
    },
    {
      title: 'actions',
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        return '<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showEditModal(this)">edit</button>'
      }
    }
  ]
})

function showEditModal(el) {
  var data = $(el.closest('table')).DataTable().row(el.closest('tr')).data();
  
  $('#modal #id').val(data.item_id);
  $('#modal #code').val(data.item_code);
  $('#modal #name').val(data.name);
  
  $('#modal').modal('show');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table id="table"></table>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="id">
        <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="code">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: data.key1 mean like i have{item_id:1, item_name:product and so on}, if get val.(data.key1) then it will take the 1st one **item_id** right?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please upvote or accept the answer. It would help me too.

Comment: how i put inside model? need to open<div id="input1">? or ? i beginner and very stupid. pls help

Comment: can you give me an example of data that you get when you run `var data = table.row(this).data();`

Comment: console show {item_id: "2", item_code: "PA", name: "Product A", short_description: null, description: null}

Comment: @BrantleyOng   i have updated the answer. please check it. if you find the answer useful, please upvote it or accept it. it will help me too.